# What is missing from my PeP proxy installation?

Tags: fiware

I am following [this tutorial](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/PEP_Proxy_-_Wilma_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide) to install PeP proxy.

I have installed both node and npm on my CentOS 6.7:

```
[root@centos fi-ware-pep-proxy]# node -v
v0.10.41
[root@centos fi-ware-pep-proxy]# npm -v
1.4.29
```

But when I get into the fi-ware-pep-proxy folder and and run `npm install`, I get the following error:

```
[root@centos fi-ware-pep-proxy]# npm install
npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,
npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm
npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the
npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
-
> node-expat@2.1.4 install /root/fi-ware-pep-proxy/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/fi-ware-pep-proxy/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlparse.o
make: cc: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/expat/deps/libexpat/lib/xmlparse.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/fi-ware-pep-proxy/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/fi-ware-pep-proxy/node_modules/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.41
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! node-expat@2.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.1.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /root/fi-ware-pep-proxy
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.41
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.29
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**I tried looking for expat-devel which I also yum installed, but the error remains the same.**

I also checked my python version and saw that it is:

```
[root@centos fi-ware-pep-proxy]# python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

**Does anyone have a clue how I can solve this issue?**

Comment: Wilma PEP Proxy is not tested in CentOS. I recommend you to use Ubuntu (recommended 14.04 LTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Álvaro Alonso I came to the conclusion that I should install gcc:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

as explained here:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6

Thank you!